# Extract last 16 character from a sentence in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to extract last 16 characters from a sentence under a title column of a table using bigquery. My table is like this:

title

No Commission inc GST - FY20 H2 Rewards Prospecting - SCC_H2_P25_0620

FB/IG - P25 to 55 - Retageting - SCC_H2_P27_0625

I would like to get the output: SCC_H2_P25_0620

```
                            SCC_H2_P27_0625
```

Can anyone please assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SUBSTR(title, LENGTH(title) - 15, 15)
```

Above extract last 15 chars from title column

```
#standardSQL
WITH test AS (
  SELECT 'No Commission inc GST - FY20 H2 Rewards Prospecting - SCC_H2_P25_0620' title UNION ALL
  SELECT 'FB/IG - P25 to 55 - Retageting - SCC_H2_P27_0625'
)
SELECT SUBSTR(title, LENGTH(title) - 15, 15)
FROM test
```

output

```
Row f0_  
1   SCC_H2_P25_062   
2   SCC_H2_P27_062
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mikhali. It works fine. You are helping me a lot.

Comment: I'm sure OP knows this by now, but for anyone else looking at this, the query above doesn't capture the very last character (off-by-one-bug), but the example SQL is clear enough to figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Based on Big Query (standard SQL) substring built-in function document,
[BigQuery Substring section](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#substring)

```
...    
If position is negative, the function counts from the end of value, with -1 indicating the last character.
...
```

Can't you do the following?

```
SUBSTR(title, -16)
```

Comment: Simple and easy! Not sure if this is a newer version of SUBSTR(), but use this answer instead of other answers.

Comment: It's a built-in function of the standard SQL from Big Query if you look at the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure how your full string looks like. If it looks like that

**'No Commission inc GST - FY20 H2 Rewards Prospecting - SCC_H2_P25_0620 FB/IG - P25 to 55 - Retageting - SCC_H2_P27_0625'**

Then I'd suggest you to use regex:

`SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL('No Commission inc GST - FY20 H2 Rewards Prospecting - SCC_H2_P25_0620 FB/IG - P25 to 55 - Retageting - SCC_H2_P27_0625', "- (SCC[^;]*) FB/IG") AS output;`

`output SCC_H2_P25_0620`

Or you can use a SUBSTR function if you know for sure that your string will always be the same length:

`SELECT SUBSTR('No Commission inc GST - FY20 H2 Rewards Prospecting - SCC_H2_P25_0620 FB/IG - P25 to 55 - Retageting - SCC_H2_P27_0625', 55, 15) AS output;`

`output SCC_H2_P25_0620`

cheers